# Add a free gift that has different sizes set via custom options?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, ce-1.9.0.1, free-gift

I am currently building a site and I am looking to give customers a free item of clothing with every purchase. I am using this extension below to try to achieve this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gift-rules-5571.html

When the customer orders anything from the site they should see a free pair of slippers appear in the basket. However the issue is that everyone needs to select the shoe size so they get the right ones.

I tried creating a product that had a required custom field of "Size" but when I added the rule to put that item as a free gift the system crashed and this was because the item was added with a required field that was empty.

Then I made that field not required and it worked thinking that the customer could edit the product in the basket and pick a different size, however when they do that a new pair of slippers is added to the cart at full price and the one set as gift isn't updated.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I can achieve this using either the extension I have installed or by another way?

Thanks

Comment: can anyone please help with this?

Comment: So basically what you want is to add a configurable product to the cart, as a gift right?

Answer (score 2):

As @Sukeshini already mentioned in the comments above, what you are looking to do is adding configurables, not simples.

You are attempting to re-create the configurable product type and functionality  by using a simple product with option(s). Do-abble, yes, but you are going down a dark rabbit hole, with many days of frustration and issues ahead of you.

Noted on the extension page that you are using, it clearly states

> only simple products are supported as gifts

(and most likely not simples with options  - ask the developer of that module about that ability)

thus I gather this is why you are trying the approach you are doing - attempting to stay within the capabilities of the module selected.

Do it right. Create configurables, and gift those. You will end up with way less hassles, bugs and sleepless nights of frustration.

You want to find a gifting module that supports the ability to gift configurables.

There are a few about, and there is one available on my own magento extension store, which comes with super support ;) (blatant self promotion - http://www.proxiblue.com.au/magento-gift-promotions.html)